# sublists of a list with possitive sum

Tags: array-algorithms

I'm trying to find the sublist of a list (with at least one positive integer) with the following 2 properties
1. the sum of it's elements is positive
2. it has the maximum length of all the other sub lists with positive sum

I'm only interesting in the length of that list. Kadane's algorithm finds the sublist with maximum sum in O(n) time. Is there an algorithm that can do the same here in O(n)? I've found a solution but it really computes all the sublists and is of course very very slow....

thank you for your time

Comment: Do the elements need to be adjacent? In other words, if I have `[10, 8, -8]`, does there exist a solution?

Comment: yes elements need to be adjacent, in [10,8,-8] the list itself is an acceptable solution (the one with the biggest lenght) and the sublist [8,-8],[10,8] . (A solution for the case that the sum is greater or equal than zero is more than welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the sum of all the numbers say it is n.
If n > 0 then return the full list as the answer.
else
keep trimming the smaller element from both ends and subtract from the sum till the sum turns positive.
Return this as the result.
It is an  O(n) algorithm.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is here. You can use [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort%E2%80%8E) to sort the array.
After that staring form the maximum element make a sum and check that if adding this element
will retain positive sum of not, if it remain positive add that and increment count move ahead. This might have some bugs for some input,i mean it may not work for all test cases.
but, this is just an idea which may help you as some improvement to this will give you your desired output.
at the end of one traversal count variable will give u result.
example:

```
array=[12,10,8,5,4,-2,-3,-20,-30] //considered already sorted now
i=0 sum=12 count=1
i=1 sum=22 count=2
i=2 sum=30 count=3
i=3 sum=35 count=4
i=4 sum=39 count=5
i=5 sum=37 count=6
i=6 sum=34 count=7
i=7 sum=14 count=8
i=8 sum=14 count=8 //as now 30 cant be added
so, here count=8 says maximum length sub array of 8 can give you positive sum.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have almost answered it already. Just modify Kadane's to use length of subsequence rather than the sum of the subsequence. That solves your problem. Here is Kadane's from Wikipedia:

```
int sequence(int numbers[])    
{ 
    // These variables can be added in to track the position of the subarray
    size_t begin = 0;
    size_t begin_temp = 0;
    size_t len_temp = 0;
    size_t end = 0;

    // Find sequence by looping through
    for(size_t i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
            // calculate max_ending_here
            if(max_ending_here < 0)
            {
                    max_ending_here = numbers[i]; 
                    begin_temp = i;
            }
            else
            {
                    max_ending_here += numbers[i];
                    len_temp += (i - begin_temp);
            }

            // calculate max_so_far_len
            if(len_temp >= max_so_far_len )
            {
                    max_so_far_len  = len_temp; 
                    begin = begin_temp;
                    end = i;
            }
    }
    return max_so_far_len ;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since in your answer u consider sub-lists as consequetive elements , I guess a slight modification in Kadane's Algo will work for you. 
Just introduce a variable named **max_length_till_now** . And update it whenever you found a sub list with length greater than it's present value.